# jQuery scroll to next element via up/down buttons - how to add handling for manual scrolling that would otherwise confuse this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to implement two static buttons for navigating up or down between about 10 containing div tags on a single fairly deep page of content.

I want the buttons to smoothly scroll to the next part of the page (next containing div) whenever they are clicked on.

The problem with this solution is that if you manually scroll up and down the page using the browser scroll bar or the mouse wheel then the logic of the code is not aware of this and when you next click next/prev a scroll takes place that is not actually relevant to the viewable area you see, totally ruining the user experience.

You can test this in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/ .    If you click NEXT once it works. Now scroll down to near the bottom of the content and click PREV.   In theory the page should go one step back from the bottom of the page.  Instead it returns to the top of the page.

Maybe I just need to scrap this code and use some external library which is fine, but I can't find anything appropriate.  Anyone have an idea on how to make my code resolve this issue?

The code I am using so far is here:

```
$('div.section').first();
$('a.display').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

  var t = $(this).text(),
  that = $(this);

if (t === 'next' && $('.current').next('div.section').length > 0) {
    var $next = $('.current').next('.section');
    var top = $next.offset().top;

    $('.current').removeClass('current');

    $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: top     
    }, function () {
           $next.addClass('current');
    });
 } else if (t === 'prev' && $('.current').prev('div.section').length > 0) {
    var $prev = $('.current').prev('.section');
    var top = $prev.offset().top;

    $('.current').removeClass('current');

    $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: top     
    }, function () {
           $prev.addClass('current');
    });
  } 
});
```

Comment: Maybe use CSS directive `overflow:hidden` to disallow manual scrolling. But be sure to have `overflow:auto` in the divs to cater for users with small screens.

Comment: Sorry @Roamer-1888, im not sure how this helps.  I have slightly rewritten my question to make it clearer as to what my problem is.

Comment: After your edit, my understanding remains the same and my suggestion seems appropriate.

Comment: @Roamer-1888,  I can't disable real scrolling I'm afraid.   I need to have both options.   ALso it doesn't deal with mouse wheel action really.  The person I'm making this for wouldn't accept these kind of half solutions I'm afraid.

Comment: Pity, 'cos that's the simplest solution.

Comment: You need to introduce a mechanism for keeping `current` up to date on manual scroll.

Comment: Any more info @Roamer-1888 ?

Comment: Try the jQuery [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin. There's still some work to do, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: You could also use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for it. Just use with the option `scrollBar:true` or `autoScrolling:false`. [Living demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html) (click on the menu)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with the wonderful jQuery inview plugin - https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview  An overview of what I did follows...

I first setup some variables, the pageItems array contains all the divs I need to monitor...

```
var posNext=0;
var posPrev=0;
var pageItems = ["pageone", "pagetwo", "pagethree", "pagefour", "pagefive"];
```

I then setup the following in document ready.  Thanks to the inview plugin and the jQuery bind event, on a page scroll (of any kind, either by my buttons, manually or via mouse wheel) the plugin is run.  I first search the array of page items for a match with what is returned by the $(this).attr("id") value.  I then adjust the posNext/posPrev variables with values based on the current div in view.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $(".divclass").bind('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
    if (isInView) {
        matchPos = pageItems.indexOf($(this).attr("id"));

        // Determine prev/next positions now we have an index.  The position values used in click events later
        if ( (matchPos+1)==pageItems.length ){
            posNext=matchPos;
            posPrev=matchPos-1;
        }else if (matchPos==0){
            posNext=matchPos+1;
            posPrev=0;
        }else{
            posNext=matchPos+1;
            posPrev=matchPos-1;
        }

    } else {
        // dont update index
    }
  });
});
```

Finally also within document.ready I have binds to catch clicks on the buttons I have on screen all the time. These use a jQuery animate call to scroll to the div id value specified via the array index values in posNext/posPrev.

```
$(".down-button").click(function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+pageItems[posNext]).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
$(".up-button").click(function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+pageItems[posPrev]).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```